# Draw a frequency distribution curve of two variables in same plot

Tags: r, plot

I am facing a problem. The following is a glimpse of my data frame `d`:

```
size        Type
1  28.63    complete
2  24.44    complete
3  31.45    complete
4  23.12    complete
5  20.86    complete
6  15.70  incomplete
7  12.77    complete
8  29.51    complete
9  28.71    complete
```

I am trying to get a separate frequency distribution curve for incomplete and complete indicated by separate symbols in the same plot, size and frequency being my x and y axis respectively.

The plot should turn out to be like this.

[image]

Comment: no its just random number

Comment: yes the size is discrete. The frequency is defined by the number of times the same size is getting repeated as it is giving the frequency of observation y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *(My earlier comment)* May I ask whether your `size` column is discrete? If yes a contingency table makes sense, otherwise we need first bin `size` into cells (possibly using `hist` as it also returns counts). I am asking this because your `size` is decimal, and is suspicious to be a continuous value.

*(Your reply)* Yes the `size` is discrete. The frequency is defined by the number of times the same size is getting repeated as it is giving the frequency of observation.

---

Consider a toy example:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- data.frame(size = c(rpois(50,3),rpois(50,5)),
                Type = gl(2, 50, labels = c("complete","incomplete")))
```

We might use `tapply` to get a contingency table using `table()` for each type:

```
y <- with(x, tapply(size, Type, table))
#$complete

# 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  8 
# 2  5 12 10 12  6  2  1 

#$incomplete

# 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 
# 5  6 13  6  7  8  4  1
```

Then we want to reorganize this list into a data frame:

```
z <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,
             lapply(y,
                    function (u) data.frame(size = c(as.numeric(names(u)),NA),
                                            freq = c(unname(u),NA))))

#             size freq
#complete.1      0    2
#complete.2      1    5
#complete.3      2   12
#complete.4      3   10
#complete.5      4   12
#complete.6      5    6
#complete.7      6    2
#complete.8      8    1
#complete.9     NA   NA
#incomplete.1    2    5
#incomplete.2    3    6
#incomplete.3    4   13
#incomplete.4    5    6
#incomplete.5    6    7
#incomplete.6    7    8
#incomplete.7    8    4
#incomplete.8    9    1
#incomplete.9   NA   NA
```

Then we can produce the plot you want:

```
# `lty = 1` for "complete", `lty = 2` for "incomplete"
with(z, plot(size, freq, lty = rep(1:2, lengths(y) + 1L), type = "l"))

#with(z, plot(size, freq, pch = "."))
#with(z, lines(size, freq, lty = rep(1:2, lengths(y) + 1L)))
```

[image]

????? Something I don't quite understand happens here. `plot` is not producing correct line type, each though I set it. As a result, I have to do this in a boring way:

```
k <- cumsum(lengths(y))
with(z, plot(size, freq, pch = "."))
with(z, lines(size[1:k[1]], freq[1:k[1]], lty = 1))
with(z, lines(size[(k[1]+1):k[2]], freq[(k[1]+1):k[2]], lty = 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with `ggplot2` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(size=c(28.63,24.44,31.45,23.12,20.86,15.70,12.77,29.51,28.71),Type=c('complete','complete','complete','complete','complete','incomplete','complete','complete','complete'))
ggplot(df, aes(linetype = Type)) + geom_density(aes(size))
```

[image]